# iPhone 5s switched Audio Channels

Tags: audio, iphone

I have an iPhone 5s phone. while hearing to some single channel audio i came to know that my audio channels are switched.

The left channel voice comes out from the right earbud and vise versa.

To do the tests i used [this website](http://www.audiocheck.net/audiotests_stereo.php). When I run the left channel audio the sound comes out of right earbud and when I run the right channel audio file the sound comes from left bud.

I have checked for audio balance and it is perfectly inbetween L and R.

Comment: Are you sure that headphones are working well and cables are not inverted?

Comment: yes sound comes out of both headphones, i dont know about cables being inverted. On my headphones R and L are written. I put them accordingly in my ears.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the headphones, the constructor invert the cable and therefore you left channel voice comes out from the right earbud and vice versa. Have you tried with another pair of headphone? Do you have the same problem?

Comment: I dont have another pair of headphones to check. Is there a solution to it?

Comment: I checked with another non-apple headphone and the sound comes fine in it. So maybe headphones are faulty. How should i fix them?

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me too with some wireless sporting earbuds. I did switched the gear that held the bud in my ear and problem solved. Every other device does work fine, just this headset was reversed. Cheaper than getting a return :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, I don't think you can invert R and L channels (at least without jailbreak, maybe with it there is some additional setting that swaps the channels).

Therefore the solutions are:

- you don't mind and continue to use your faulty headphones. (I'm not an expert of stereo sound but I think there will not be a lot of differences).
- You buy a new pair of headphones.
- Or maybe, if the faulty one are Apple, you can ask in a Apple Store support for a new properly working pair.